# Connection Forbidden

Tags: connection, ibm-connections

When I'm trying to connect to my connections which is "https://connections.iainnovation.com/hompage"
The browser shows:

> Forbidden, You don't have permission to access /homepage/ on this server, IBM_HTTP_Server at connections.iainnovation.com Port 443

What seems to be the problem? I've already check the possible error just like my "host file, httpconfd, path of plugins-cfg.xml"

And checking the log of my connections it shows this error "[error] [client 192.168.10.123] Directory index forbidden by options directive: C:/IBM/HTTPServer/htdocs/homepage/"

What seems to be the problem? I'm just a beginner on connections.

Answer (score 0):

check your plugin-cfg.xml does it point to the right server/applications? 
I imagine it doesn't otherwise you shouldn't see htdocs in the warning

sounds like when you updated it, you might have to manually copy over the xml. 
**make sure you overwrite the plugin-cfg.xml **

That should fix your problem.